# Why does my code stop running? VBA Initatiate one file that closes another before continuing.

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Sub auto_open()

   Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
        "D:\umc\030_DOI19980929\120_Automation_Files\Auto_UpdateDOI.xls" _
        , UpdateLinks:=3).RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen

        Application.Run "Auto_UpdateDOI.xls!AutoUpdate"

End Sub
```

The above file opens a file called AutoUpdate DOI

```
Sub Autoupdate()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False

    Call Flat

    Workbooks("Auto_Root.xls").Close
    Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
        "D:\umc\040_OPM19970417\120_Automation_Files\Auto_UpdateOPM.xls" _
        , UpdateLinks:=3).RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen

     Application.Run "Auto_UpdateOPM.xls!Autoupdate"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Why does AutoUpdateDOI stop working after Auto_Root is closed? If I move   Workbooks("Auto_Root.xls").Close to the bottom it of the sub it will still run but I want the Auto_Root file to close before I run Auto_UpdateOPM

Comment: FROM which file is this running?

Answer (score 2):

The code stops running because you've closed the file that contains it. Just because your first procedure called code in another file doesn't mean that the code in the first file isn't still running. When you close that file, the thread is interrupted and the code stops.